# Excel Subtracting periods from specific dates using 360-day calendar?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Got formulas for figuring my differences between date periods in days as follows:

`=IF(F7="","0",DAYS360(F6,F7)+1)`

This gives the days result for each period that I am interested in, but I then need to add each period of days together and subtract them from a current date (like doing service computation). The issue is that I need to do this second calculation within a 360-day calendar as well.  If I just try to do a `days360()` formula with one value being the current date and the other being the total number of days that I need to backtrack, then the "original" date that it comes up with is drastically off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the equivalent of the difference between NETWORKDAYS and WORKDAY functions. The former counts working days between two dates, the latter adds working days to a date, you essentially want the WORKDAY equivalent for DAYS360, which I don't think exists.

You can manipulate DAYS360, though, e.g. with a date in A2 and number of days to subtract (in 360 day mode) in B2 you can use this formula for the date

`=A2-B2-MATCH(B2,INDEX(DAYS360(A2-B2-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&CEILING(B2/30,1))),A2),0),0)`